# cant pass the request to policy so i can validate some issues

Tags: api, request, authorization, laravel-5.6, policy

i authorize store like this

```
    public function store( Request $request)
{
    $this->authorizeApi('store',JobPost::class, $request);
    return $this->jobPostRepository->store($request);
}
```

and in policies my store method looks like this

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user=auth()->user();
    return ($user->company_id == $request->company_id)
        &&($request->expiration_date->isAfter($request->publish_date))
        &&($request->publish_date->isAfter(now()))
        ;
}
```

when i run this i get

```
"Argument 1 passed to App\Policies\JobPostPolicy::store() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of App\Models\User given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\balatar1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 481"
```

when i dd the request in the controller its ok but when i dd it on the policy it returs a null User object!!! why is that?

Comment: You have to change your policy method to this: `store(User $user, Request $request)`, the User model instance is always passed first.

Comment: @ChinLeung when i do that it returns : [code]Too few arguments to function App\Policies\JobPostPolicy::store(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\balatar1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 481 and exactly 2 expected

Comment: @ChinLeung even when i change my controller to send $user i give the same error: ' $user=auth()->user();
        $this->authorizeApi('store',JobPost::class, $user, $request);'

Comment: Can you show me your `authorizeApi` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did some mistakes and miss something.

As I know you have some companies and each `Company` has some `JobPost`s.

First, you should not pass your company id in the body of job post request instead, your store route should be something like `https://example.com/company/{company_id}/job-post` then you are able to catch company model via the Laravel model binding!

so your routes should be defined as:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'company', 'as' => 'company.'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => '{company}'], function () {
        Route::resource('job-post', 'JobPostController', ['parameters' => ['job-post' => 'jobPost']);
    });
    Route::resource('', 'ComapnyController', ['parameters' => ['' => 'company']);
}
```

And your controller looks like (I'll have explained the `JobPostRequest` by the second part of the answer):

```
class JobPostController extends Controller
{
    public function store(JobPostRequest $request, Company $company)
    {
        $this->authorizeApi('store', [JobPost::class, $company]);

        // the rest...
    }
}
```

Second, What you need is a Request class to do validations for you.

based on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests) firstly you have to create a `Request` class, then it needs to run `php artisan make:request JobPostRequest`

Then your job post request should be something like:

```
class BaseRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'body' => 'required|max:65535',
        ];
    }
}
```

You could also do what you've done in your policy, in the above class `authorize` method but is not recommended.

Third, In your policy (`JobPostPloicy`) you'll have to check if currently logged in user is able to post a job for the given `$company` or not.

P.S. Please copy and past your classes completely with all dependencies and spend a little more time to butify your post. If this is hard to write your question, this is hard to read, understand, and answer it correctly.